# What's the easiest/best way to profile a math intensive C++ application for speed on Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, profiling, valgrind, scientific-computing

I am devolping a console math intensive application on Mac OS X. It's implemented in C++, and I'm using no special IDE, just a plain text editor, and GCC for compiling.

Currently, my implementation is quite slow with my data. What is the easiest/best way to profile it to know which parts to optimize?

I use valgrind, at a very basic level, to check for memory leaks. However, I never used it (callgrind) for computing speed profiling. How should I do it? I find callgrind documentation a little confusing/not very newbie friendly. Is there a kcachegrind equivalent for Mac? As far as I know, Maccachegrind only works with xdebug output, and doesn't work with callgrind 3.6.0 output.

Is it better to use valgrind or gprof for profiling? I am not familiar with neither.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you use GDB? Then this works: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/375913/what-can-i-use-to-profile-c-code-in-linux/378024#378024

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
/Developer/Applications/Performance Tools/Shark.app
```

Open it, run your application, hit start, let your app run for a bit, hit stop.

There's a [more detailed introduction](http://developer.apple.com/tools/sharkoptimize.html) on the Apple developer site.

Comment: I'll accept this answer since I've become fond of using Apple Instruments for profiling.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to install kcachegrind from Macports (package kdesdk4) and maybe also fink (which I never used myself) and use it just as you do on Linux. I did that in the past and it worked fine.